# How can I concatenate two lookup columns in SharePoint?

Tags: json, sharepoint, lookup, power-automate

I have 3 SharePoint Lists:

1. Application
2. Interface
3. Dataflow

The Application List shows a list of applications with there details.
The Interface List has two lookup columns to the Application List, called Input & Output.

Therefore:

> 'Application'.[Title] = 'Interface'[Input]
>
> 'Application'.[Title] = 'Interface'[Output]

I then have a Title column, in which I'd like to concatenate the [Input] & [Output] column with ' to ' in the middle.

*For Example: Application table has Excel and SQL as 2 records. The [Input] column grabs Excel, the [Output] column grabs SQL, thus the [Title] column should say 'Excel to SQL', which is the name of the Interface.*

Currently I am doing this manually. In the title column I am writing 'Excel to SQL'.
The Dataflow list, then has a lookup to Title in the Interface list.

Therefore:

> 'Interface'.[Title] = 'Dataflow'.[Interface]

In short, I need a way to concatenate 2 lookup columns to create a column that is used as a lookup column for another table.

**What I've Tried:**

1. *Creating a Calculated Column*: Unfortunately you cannot create a calculated column with lookup columns.
2. *Using Json*: I've used the following code under column formatting in the title column, which works "kind of"

> "$schema":
> "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
> "elmType": "div",   "txtContent": "= [$Inout.lookupValue] + ' to ' +
> [$Output.lookupValue]" }

It returns what I need it to say, but not in plain text, therefore I am unable to use it has a lookup column to my dataflow list.

3. *Using Power Automate:* I believe this is the only route that will be successful, I just cannot seem to figure out the flow and have not been able to find any solution elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, calculated column and JSON formatting will not work for you scenario. You will either have to use the Power Apps customized list forms or Power automate flow (which will run on item creation/update) to update the Title column value in Interface list.